# Fully expose dashboard/reporting in visualforce page. Possible?

Tags: visualforce, reporting, customer-portal, dashboard

We have a fully customized Visualforce app that is available to customer portal users. Users are automatically directed to the VF pages and have no access to the standard SF customer portal. We want to expose the dashboard/reporting functionality to these users to allow them to create and view reports/dashboards directly from the app.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this you'll need to roll your own reports and dashboards.  From personal experience this can be a real pain due to the slow queries this requires and the large number of records you'll need to process.  However, if the record volumes for your use case or on the small side (<1k) this may be something to consider.

Report and dashboards are a feature that Salesforce views as a value add and they want you to pay for it by buying a more expensive license than a customer portal user.

Answer (score 0):

We can probably embed Reports and Dashboards in Visualforce pages.

Per my understanding, reports can be shown in the customer portal. But it is not available for all types of portal users. For example:  not available to the High volume portal user licenses.

Also to the best of my knowledge, dashboards cannot be shown on the portal.

There are a few ideas on the community about this but I don't think that functionality is available yet. 
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrkB